# Как сохранить строку в массив?

Tags: c

Пишу программу, которая будет читать файл, парсить его и записывать данные в массив. Данные в файле задаются пользователем перед началом выполнения программы. На данном этапе, в файле содержиться только 2 строчки.

```
communication1 : b8:27:eb:cf:54:2c, b8:27:eb:75:85:e4, 2000000;
communication2 : mm:27:eb:cf:54:2c, xx:27:eb:75:85:e4, 2200000;
```

Программ должна корректо определять мак1, мак2 и время. Для этого я создаю соотвествующие массивы типа `char`. Но проблема в том, что данные в него не записываются.

Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
    int count = 2, i = 0;
    char *Mac1[4], *Mac2[4], *Trash[4], *Time[4];
    int k=0;
    char tempbuff[100];
    char trash[20], mac1[20], mac2[20], time[20];
    FILE *fptr =  fopen("config", "r");
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while(!feof(fptr)){
       if (fgets(tempbuff,100,fptr)) {
               printf("\n%s", tempbuff);
               sscanf(tempbuff, "%15s : %17[^;], %17[^;], %17[^;];", trash, mac1, mac2, time);
                Trash[i] = trash;
                Mac1[i] = mac1;
                Mac2[i] = mac2;
                Time[i] = time;
                printf ("i is %d\n", i);
                printf("Mac1 is %s,Mac2 is %s, Time is %s trash, is %s \n", Mac1[0], Mac2[i], Time[i], Trash[i]);
       }
       i++;
    }

    printf(" \n Mac 0 is %s \n", Mac1[0]);


    fclose(fptr);

}
```

После запуска программы, все работатет корректно - есть строка и она разбивается на соответствующие переменные, которые, вроде как, записываются в массивы.

Вывод программы:

```
communication1 : b8:27:eb:cf:54:2c, b8:27:eb:75:85:e4, 2000000;
i is 0
Mac1 is b8:27:eb:cf:54:2c,Mac2 is b8:27:eb:75:85:e4, Time is 2000000 trash, is communication1 

communication2 : mm:27:eb:cf:54:2c, xx:27:eb:75:85:e4, 2200000;
i is 1
Mac1 is mm:27:eb:cf:54:2c,Mac2 is xx:27:eb:75:85:e4, Time is 2200000 trash, is communication2
```

Однако, если после этого я хочу вывести первый элемент массива `Mac1`, то получаю то, что должно было находиться во втором элементе. Т.е. я **ожидаю**, что после срабатывания команды

```
printf(" \n Mac 0 is %s \n", Mac1[0]);
```

я увижу `Mac 0 is b8:27:eb:cf:54:2c`,

**но результат**

```
Mac 0 is mm:27:eb:cf:54:2c
```

Я предпологаю, что я как-то не так работаю с массивом для сохранения строк. Но что именно я делаю криво - я не вижу, в связи с чем и возник вопрос - как сохранить строку в массив?

Comment: [man strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) (вы копируете адреса массивов, которые потом перезаписываются)

Comment: @avp strdup сработало, спасибо Вам большое

Comment: У вас нет никакого "массива для сохранения строк" . У вас есть массив для сохранения *указателей* на строки. Вот с понимания этого факта надо и начинать.